# How to do type conversion for the following Scenario?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using

TCHAR buffer[MAX_SIZE];

after some set of steps i am gettig the relative path of folder say for ex:

c:\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.037\

Since the above path is in buffer of type TCHAR and i am trying to **concatenate**"RegAsm.exe"

After Appending i need to convert the path to the LPCTSTR since i need to pass it to 
CreateProcess() which takes LPCTSTR type as argument

then the compiler giving error.I have tried but vexed.

can any one help me in this aspect....

Comment: Are you doing something like buffer + "RegAsm.exe"  which is resulting in compiler error?

Comment: TCHAR.H is used to make it possible creating Unicode (Utf16), MS Multibyte and good old 8 bit codepage code using one source code. Its made by use of preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is TCHAR and CreateProcess are macros that expand differently depending on whether you compile for Unicode or not. The caveat is that GetCORSystemDirectory() will only accept a Unicode buffer. To get rid of these ANSI/Unicode problems write this code part explicitly for Unicode.

Instead of TCHAR use WCHAR for the buffer. Instead of CreateProcess() use CreateProcessW() - it will happily accept the Unicode buffer. Use wcscat() for strings concatenation.

Something like this (error handling omitted):

```
 WCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH + 1];
 DWORD realLength;
 GetCORSystemDirectory( buffer, MAX_PATH, &realLength );
 *( buffer + realLength ) = 0;// Don't forget to null-terminate the string
 wcscat( buffer, L"regasm.exe" );
 CreateProcessW( /*pass buffer here*/ );
```

Comment: But When Using CreateProcessW() can not convert the STARTUPINFO &si to LPSTARTUPINFOW so i have used (LPSTARTUPINFOW)&si in CreateProcW() then it working fine.....

Thank u very much for ur suuport..

Comment: You should instead declare the variable of STARTUPINFOW type - that would be more correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
_tcscat_s
```

is the related method for TCHAR. It depends like TCHAR on the _UNICODE & _MBCS preprocessor swithch and will be resolved to strcat_s or wcscat_s.

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_SIZE] = _T("c:\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.037\");
_tcscat_s(buffer, MAX_SIZE, _T("RegAsm.exe"));
```

but this is very good old C style. So while you are using TCHAR I would suggest that
you also use MFC stuff. So using CString which also is affected by _UNICODE & _MBCS would also solve your issue.

```
CString buffer;
buffer = _T("c:\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.037\");
buffer += _T("RegAsm.exe");
CreateProcess(buffer, ..
```

std::string or std::wstring will not help because they do not change their behavior related to the preprocessor switched but if you use CreateProcessA or CreateProcessW you can also use std::string or std::wstring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your life easier I would always suggest using std::string, then when calling the CreateProcess() function just do:

```
std::string myPath = "somePath";
LPCTSTR lpBuf = reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>(myPath.c_str());
```

Not tested but that should probably work, if you are still getting an error, well posting the code would be beneficial.

Note that it may be more complicated if you are using Unicode.

Comment: Never use this reinterpret cast.
LPCTSTR lpBuf = myPath.c_str(); will also work if the system is configured right.

Comment: This should never be done. If string::c_str() is ANSI doing this reinterpret_cast will surely lead to passing garbage into later called CreateProcess. It's not a fix to the problem, just a way to ask the compiler to not show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the fact that you get an error that you're working with Unicode... In which case you may want to look at the *mbstowcs* and *wcstombs* functions.

More information is really needed to be able to answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you do buffer + "RegAsm.exe", it will be like adding two pointers (as arrays decay into pointers and "RegAsm.exe" will be const TCHAR*) hence you get the compiler error. What you want is string concatanation. Use [_tcscat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282(VS.80).aspx) or or the secure version (as claimed in MSDN) [_tcscat_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4(VS.80).aspx) function for doing the concatanation.